# Reading MP3 Tag size header: why does 257 = 00 00 02 01?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, mp3

I'm trying to familiarise myself with the structure of MP3 files. I am reading this article http://www.multiweb.cz/twoinches/MP3inside.htm#FrameHeaderA

When reading about the ID3 header and trying to read the tag size which states:

Size of TAG is encoded into 4 Bytes. But not to be so easy, the most significant bit in each Byte is set to 0 and ignored. Only remaining 7 bits are used. The reason is to avoid mismatch with audio frame header which has the first synchro Byte FF).
Eg. TAG len 257 is encoded as 00 00 02 01.
Size of TAG doesnt contain header itself so total lenght of previous TAG is 257 + 10 Bytes.

I do not understand how 257 is represented by 00 00 02 01.
I am familiar with 8 bits in a byte and the bits are represented in binary but am lost here. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/id3/id3v2com-00.html

7 bits per byte. so first byte value is 0 * 2^21, second is 0 * 2^14, third is 2 * 2^7 and the last is the value of 1.
Add those values up to get 257.

0 * 2^21 = 0

0 * 2^14 = 0

2 * 2^7  = 256

1 = 1

257